# Read HTML table and input data into MySQL database

Tags: html, mysql, bash, ubuntu, automation

I have a HTML page

```
table.html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to `lynx -dump` this page and insert the data from the html table into a mysql database (The HTML page will always have the same headings but the data will change daily.

I would like to get this script going and then add to a cron so I don't have to manually input the data as i am at the moment!

Does anybody know anyway to do this as I am really stuck at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any off-the-shelf solution. If you're not afraid of some Python coding, I think that would be quite easy with BeautifulSoup to navigate in your html (not such an easy task in itself).

You would have something like :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="xxx",db="xxx")
c=db.cursor()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)

tr_list=soup.find_all("tr")
for tr in tr_list:
  cell1=tr.find_all("td")[0]
  cell2=tr.find_all("td")[1]
  #do your sql insert here
  c.execute ("SQL query here")
c.close()
```